# Border radius in every browser that supports it

Tags: css

I am using the following:

```
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
border-radius:10px;
```

What I would like is to confirm if this covers every browser that currently supports the border radius property. I just want to be sure I have as much coverage as possible.

Advice would be much appreciated

Robert

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983666/css-border-radius-which-is-the-correct-style-to-use-border-radius-webkit-bord/1990469#1990469) may help you.

Answer (score 3):

```
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
border-radius:10px;
```

This will be supported by Mozilla Firefox, Opera, Safari, Google Chrome and IE9.

Read this for more:- http://jonraasch.com/blog/css-rounded-corners-in-all-browsers

Answer (score 0):

At present Opera (version 10.5 onward), Safari (version 5 onward), Chrome (version 5 onward) and ie9

you can find information about css3 border radius here:

http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/

Answer (score 0):

From [CSSTricks](http://css-tricks.com/do-we-need-box-shadow-prefixes/):

> Firefox 3.6- needs `-moz-`. From 4 up, unprefixed is fine. On this site, that's 0.3% of the 30% or so that use Firefox.
>
> Safari 4- needs `-webkit-`. That's even smaller for this site. 0.1% of the 10% or so using Safari.
>
> iOS 3.x needs `-webkit-` too, which means an iPhone 3GS or iPad 1 that have never been upgraded, which is the smallest number yet.
>
> (...) 1% for all this combined

So just go with `border-radius` without those prefixes.